# ERIC MARTIN Simple Modal window close event is not working when i am showing another dialog popup over that....?

Tags: jquery-ui, simplemodal

I am using simple modal window to show dynamic content(table) on modal window popup. The close event is working fine when I am simply showing data in modal window.

But if I am showing another jquery dialog popup on simple modal window after closing jquery popup dialog, My simple modal window popup onClose event is not working.

```
   // Base Modal popup
   $('#simple').modal({
       onShow: function() { 
           alert("activated"); 
       },
       onClose: function() {
           alert("deactivated");
           $.modal.close(); 
       }
   });

   // Jquery popup
   $('#kick').dialog({
       //ajax calls to show data  
   });
```

close event is not working second time even when I am using `$.modal.close();`
Please... please help me... I had already spent one day in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     // I get rid of this

            $("#basic-modal-content").modal( {
    onShow : function() {
          // anything you want to do before 
               },
    onClose : function() {
        // when closing popup anything you wanna do 
        var a = this;
        a.close();
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas since I dont' have VS2010 on this computer and can't confirm the actual syntax :(

```
$('#simple').close();
$(this).modal.close();
this.close();
```

though, this is how we close a dialogue box:

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

so maybe this will work?

```
$(this).modal("close");
```

Comment: $("#basic-modal-content").modal( {
  onShow : function() {
   alert("before show");                  

  },
  onClose : function() {
   alert("before closing");                           
   var a = this;
   a.close();
  }

 });

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to open the second popup after closing the first one which takes around 2 sec. So, if you use settimeout() function and call the second pop by providing 2sec delay or greater than this. It will work. Since, this is not a proper way to do so. But it actually works for me.

I am using Simple modal jquery plugin: Here is the code:

```
$('#forgot_password_modal').click(function (e) {
$.modal.close(); // this is written to close all the popups.
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#forgot_password_form').modal({   //to open a second popup
        minHeight:570,
        minWidth:600,
        maxWidth:671,
        opacity: 90,
    onOpen: function(dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                dialog.data.hide();
                dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    dialog.data.slideDown('slow');

                });
            });
        },
        onClose: function(dialog) {
            dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function() {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                    });
                });
            });
        }});
}, 2000);    
    return false;
});
```